# Trying to install kubuntu - ubi-partman failed with exit code 141

Tags: linux, partitioning, kubuntu

I first had installed ubuntu 13.10 dual boot with windows 8. I had 4 partitions, the one with Ubuntu, the one with windows, a partition "System reserved" which I think has the boot flag also and a partition with my personal stuff.
As seen in gparted, those were like this:

```
/dev/sda1 - linux 

/dev/sda2 - windows

/dev/sda3 - system reserved

/dev/sda4 - extended

   /dev/sda5 - with personal stuff
```

Then I decided to install kubuntu and I got the error saying ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. I read on some forums that this is caused by the existing ubuntu partition. I then selected "try kubuntu", installed gparted and deleted /dev/sda1. Still I had the same error. Then I rebooted and the grub bootloader was still working ( I guess it was written to mbr ) and I tought it may cause that error and used easy bcd on windows and rewrote the mbr. Now everything seems to be good, it boots directly into windows but I have the same error when I try to install kubuntu.

So, my question is, how do I get rid of this error without losing windows and my personal stuff ?

LE: I get this error in the second step of installation, when it check wether I have enough disk space, internet connection and wether my laptop is plugged in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem.

Doing a swarch for it comes up with a few options, but none of them worked for me.

Eventually I made a new live USb and allocated 1Gb free. So I could make some changes and the live USB had some more space to make mountpoints. This did the trick...

Sharad